# Subset vector based on table of logical values R

Tags: r, loops, vector, boolean, subset

I am trying to subset a vector based on a number of inputs. file.list will be a vector of filenames that I want to subset, and species will be the species names I want to search for within the files.

```
file.list <- c("blah_cod", "blah_had", "blah_ggu", "blah_cod")
species <- c("cod", "had")
a<-sapply(species, grepl, file.list, ignore.case=TRUE)

       cod   had
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE

file.list[a[,1]] 
file.list[a[,2]]
```

With the code I have currently I am able to get what I need, but I need to be able to automate it such that the number of columns will depend on the number of species input by the user. I tried looping like this:

```
for (i in (1:ncol(a))){b<-file.list[a[,i]]}
```

I have also tried a number of combinations along these lines, but either get only part of the information I need or errors. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of errors did you get? Could you paste them here, please?

Comment: How shall your result look like?

Comment: Well the usual error I get if I try other methods to the loop shown is: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Are you looking for `lapply(species, grep, file.list, ignore.case=TRUE, value=TRUE)`?

Comment: Thanks Roland that'd do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` can be used to actually return the matches instead of logical values:

```
lapply(species, grep, file.list, ignore.case=TRUE, value=TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "blah_cod" "blah_cod"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "blah_had"
```